# Widget : No Launcher activity found

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I already see the questions about "No Launcher activity found!".

I developped a widget which worked well and suddenly I have this error.

I have a configure activity declared with an intent filter `APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE`.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tina.prime"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.3.2">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name="tina.prime.TheWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/config" />
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="tina.prime.UpdateWidgetService"></service>
        <activity android:name=".ConfigureActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: No. I always have the error, or another one. See below.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you everything: *No Launcher activity found*
This means that you haven't declared any activity in your manifest as a launcher, in order to fix this, pick the activity you want to use for starting the app, and add the following attribute to it:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: When i add :   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> in the manifest, the error disappears but on the device the activity is launched before choosing the widget and the widget can be installed on the screen (error: the application is not installed).  Please help.